# Perl HTTP POST request with Content type and Authorization token

Tags: perl, http-headers, http-post, content-type, lwp-useragent

I need to send an HTTP POST request with the following HTTP headers:

```
Content-type: 'application/atom+xml'
Authorization: MyLogin auth=$token
```

The token is coming from an authorization subroutine. Here is the Perl making the actual request after the subroutine is successful:

```
my  $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my  $req = $ua->post ( $url );
    $req = header('Content-type' => 'application/atom+xml');
    $req = header('Authorization' => "MyLogin auth=$token");
```

However, I receive the following error when run:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::header called ...
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [LWP::UserAgent documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#REQUEST-METHODS), you can set additional headers by passing them as arguments to `post`:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->post($url,
    'Content-type' => 'application/atom+xml',
    'Authorization' => "MyLogin auth=$token"
);
```

Note that `$ua->post` actually sends the request, so trying to set the headers *after* calling it, as you do in your example code, is useless. (Not to mention the fact that there is no `header` function in the `main` namespace unless you import it from somewhere or write it yourself.)